# Linux Kernel Config Scopes within VM or Hypervisor

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine

In production we're going to deploy a redis server and need to set the `overcommit_memory=1` and disable Transparent Huge Pages in Kernel.

The issue is currrently we only have **one** giant server, and it is to be shared by many other apps. We only want those kernel configs in the redis server. I wonder if we can achieve it by spinning up a dedicated VM for redis. Doing so in docker certainly doesn't make sense. My questions is:

1. Will those Kernel configs take actual effect in the redis VM even if the host OS doesn't have the same configs?　I doubt it since the hardware resource is allocated by the host machine in the end.
2. Will the kernel config in the redis VM affect other VMs that run other apps? I think it won't, just want to confirm.
3. To achieve the goal, what kind of VM or hypervisor should we use?

If there's no way to do it in VM, is having a separate server (hardware) for redis the only way to go?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a real kernel on a virtual machine, the VM should be able to correctly handle overcommitted memory.

1. The host server will grant a fixed chunk of memory to the VM. The VM should manage that memory as it sees fit, including overcommitting its own address space.
2. This will not affect other applications running on the host (apart from the fact that is has less memory available). If it does, there is a problem with your hypervisor.
3. This should work with any Hypervisor. KVM is a good place to start.

Note that I have not actually tried this -- experiment results are welcome!